# How to get sum of "temp" column values from this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU4k3.jpg)How to get sum of temp column:

```
select Split_Part("EmpName",'_',1),
       "EmployeeID",
       sum("TotalDays"::decimal) as "temp" 
from "Leave_Log" 
where date("StartDate") between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31' 
  and "Staus"='Approved' 
  and "EmployeeID" in (Select "UserName" 
                      from  "Master_Employees" 
                      where "Status"='Y')
group by "EmpName","EmployeeID" 
order by "EmpName"
```

Comment: Do you mean nested aggregation?

Comment: Sample data with expected output will help

Comment: @OtoShavadze inserted image shows the output which i'm getting from query..Highlighted total is excepted output along with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks wrong GROUP BY:

```
select Split_Part("EmpName",'_',1) splited_name,
       "EmployeeID",
       sum("TotalDays"::decimal) as "temp" 
from "Leave_Log" 
where date("StartDate") between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31' 
  and "Staus"='Approved' 
  and "EmployeeID" in (Select "UserName" 
                      from  "Master_Employees" 
                      where "Status"='Y')
group by splited_name,"EmployeeID" 
order by splited_name
```

for example: if you have table

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass),
  email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  salary integer,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT users_email_key UNIQUE (email)
)
```

Then requests

```
SELECT Split_Part(email, '@', 2) split_email, sum(salary)
  FROM users
  GROUP BY email
  ORDER BY email
```

AND

```
SELECT Split_Part(email, '@', 2) split_email, sum(salary)
  FROM users
  GROUP BY split_email
  ORDER BY split_email
```

will give you different response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a column with `total sum of temp` then you should use the [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-window.html)

```
select Split_Part("EmpName",'_',1) splited_name,
       "EmployeeID",
       sum("TotalDays"::decimal) as "temp",
       sum(sum("TotalDays"::decimal)) OVER () as total
```